# Can't get JFrame simple paint-like program to work with keybindings

Tags: java, graphics, paint, repaint, keyevent

There are no errors or sth, just a transparent screen (It will copy the background) and a drawn oval, but whenever i try to type an arrow key in the keyboard it won't work. I have added the KeyListener and extended the class to JFrame, but it still does nothing. I know it is just beginner stuff, but I am a beginner myself, and this has been bugging me :/  . Also, I have also used repaint(); ,  but still it re-renders the background? Thanks for the help in advance!

```
package JavaMain;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class javamain extends JFrame {
int x, y;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public class AL extends KeyAdapter {

    private int keycode;
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void keypress(KeyEvent event) {
        keycode = event.getKeyCode();
        if (keycode == event.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= 10;
        }
        if (keycode == event.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += 10;
        }
        if (keycode == event.VK_UP) {
            y -= 10;
        }
        if (keycode == event.VK_DOWN) {
            y += 10;
        }
    }

    public void keyrelease(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}

public javamain() {
    addKeyListener(new AL());
    setTitle("Statistic");
    setSize(600, 800);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    x = 200;
    y = 200;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
    repaint();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new javamain();
}
}
```

Comment: You might want to go over the formatting of this question. The title is a little long for what you're asking and your question is one long chunk of text.
Do you use an IDE? They help a lot with debugging and code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with your KeyListener.

The AL class isn't using the right method names.

Should be keyPressed and keyReleased as far as I am aware.

```
private class AL extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {

        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();

        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            x -= 10;
        }
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            x += 10;
        }
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            y -= 10;
        }
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            y += 10;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Without changing any of your other code this seems to work.

Comment: thank you, this fixed it. also, what about the re-rendering screen? i have repaint(); , it still renders the background?